# Jquery trigger not working with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with jquery and php,Right now i have anchor tag and i want to click/trigger after form submit automatically, For this i am using following code,i am getting alert but button is not "triggered", Where i am wrong ?

PHP Code

```
if($this->session->flashdata('img_error'))
{    
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('its working');
            $('#kyc2').click();
        </script>
    ";

    echo '
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        '.$this->session->flashdata("img_error").'
        </div>
    ';
}
```

Here is html code

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a  class="nav-link" id="kyc2" data-toggle="tab" href="#KYC" role="tab" aria-controls="KYC">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/frontend/images/icon/manage.svg" alt="Image">    
        <span>KYC</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you suck? Is this really a PHP problem? If not, please share the **generated** markup, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase Please see my question carefully , i already mentioned what i tried

Comment: Then please remove the irrelevant parts from your question, and continue debugging. Also, please share the markup for the button you are talking about

Comment: is the script tag above the HTML? it seems to be the case. If yes move the script below to the HTML.

Comment: @Suzi you can use onclick event of jquery where you can write function to use anchor tag after onclick of button. RIght?

Answer (score 1):

- PHP treats `$` in a double quote as a variable so you have to
  escape it to return it as a raw character.
- You might also want to wait for `#kyc2` to be loaded into the DOM
  before you `click()` on it.

Change the PHP part to something like this

```
if($this->session->flashdata('img_error'))
{    
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('its working');
            \$('#kyc2').click();
        </script>
    ";

    echo '
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        '.$this->session->flashdata("img_error").'
        </div>
    ';
}
```